# Oracle Linux 6.7 -bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, disk-usage, xargs, oracle-linux

I have a path of about 1 million folders with a total size of 300GB. When I run the `du -sh *` command, I get the error I mentioned in the title. How can I combine using `xargs` with this command or will `xargs` solve my problem? However, I still need a separate command to find folders larger than 20GB under the same path. Need help to use these two commands.

Path example: `/data/dataold/exports/`

The output should be like below (You can think of what I have stated below as the file and folder names under the main path I have specified on the above line
):

> ```
> 4.0K xyz.sh
> 12K asdasda.txt
> 10G QWERT
> 1G ASDFGH
> ```

Best regards.

Comment: `ncdu` is a very nice utility for this purpose.

Comment: Possibly of interest: accessing a million-sized directory is horribly slow in most filesystems (which is why usually deeper trees are used). If the filenames are not random, usually each filename is stored in xx/yy/zz/filename, where xx, yy, zz are taken from a fast hash of "filename" itself. That allows much faster access in almost all scenarios.

Comment: Would `du -hd1` work? That tells `du` to list each first-level subdirectory itself, rather than first having the shell enumerate them and try to pass the entire list as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `find`, but I suggest one of the other solutions shown below.

```
find /data/dataold/exports -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \;
```

Assuming that `/data/dataold/exports` contains the subdirectories

```
foo
bar
baz
```

(and maybe more), it will run

```
du -sh /data/dataold/exports/foo
du -sh /data/dataold/exports/bar
du -sh /data/dataold/exports/baz
```

etc.

Option `-mindepth` avoids running the `du` command for `/data/dataold/exports`, and `-maxdepth` avoids this for subdirectories of a subdirectory, e.g. for `/data/dataold/exports/foo/something`.

As suggested in [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas)' comment, you can use

```
find /data/dataold/exports -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \+
```

instead of `... -exec du -sh {} \;`, if your version of `find` supports this. With `+` instead of `;`, `find` will execute `du` once for every time the linux arg buffer is filled (approx 2MB) instead of executing it once for every file/directory. The former is *much* faster.

Citing [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)' comment: "Note that calling several independent invocations of `du` (like with `find -exec`) may give different numbers if there are hard links across those top level directories, as they won't get deduplicated if found by different invocations of `du`."

---

With GNU `du` you can limit the depth to be displayed using option `-d` or `--max-depth=N`:

```
du -h -d 1 /data/dataold/exports
```

This will do the calculation for all subdirectories but limit the output to a depth of 1 below the starting point, so in the example shown above it should print the total size for

```
/data/dataold/exports/foo
/data/dataold/exports/bar
/data/dataold/exports/baz
```

etc. and for

```
/data/dataold/exports
```

The second solution, if available, should be preferred because it doesn't need to start a new `du` process for every subdirectory (in case of `-exec ... \;`) or for every set of subdirectories that fills up the arguments buffer (in case of `-exec ... \+`).

If your version of `du` does not support option `-d` you can use

```
du -h /data/dataold/exports
```

and filter the output to remove everything below the first level of subdirectories.

---

If you want to filter the output by numeric comparison, I suggest to omit the option `-h`. To avoid waiting for the slow file system access while testing the filtering, I suggest to redirect the output to a file, e.g.

```
du -d 1 /data/dataold/exports > outputfile
```

or

```
du -d 1 /data/dataold/exports 2>errors | tee outputfile
```

and process the contents of `outputfile` later.

Example:

```
awk '$1 > 20e9` outputfile
```

If your `du` doesn't support option `-d` you could use something like

```
du /data/dataold/exports > outputfile
awk '$1 > 20e9 && $1 != /\/.*\/.*\/.*\/.*\/.*/` outputfile
```

This will print all lines that have a number bigger than 20 * 10^9 in the first field and a value that does not contain 5 (or more) slashes in the second field. The number of slashes in the second condition is tailored to the starting directory `/data/dataold/exports` and will print e.g. `/data/dataold/exports/foo` but not e.g. `/data/dataold/exports/foo/bar`.

Comment: Hi Bodo. Thank you for your answer. Can I use your first option with du -sh * , and do you know how can I use your first option for finding folders larger than 20GB? Best regards.

Comment: @jrdba123 The main point is **not** to use `*` because this would be replaced with a list of all file and directory names, possibly resulting in the "Argument list too long" error. You should not ask two different questions in one post. I suggest to write a separate question about finding directories larger than 20GB with a link to this question. Use the gray "share" below your question to get the link.

Comment: Hi Bodo, the main problem is that there are 1 million folders under the path I specified, and I want to find the size of each one separately. Using du -sh alone only gives me the size for the main path, I know it's 300GB already.

Comment: @jrdba123 Did you try the command? It should call `du` individually for every file or directory in `/data/dataold/exports`. Try `find /data/dataold/exports -maxdepth 1` to see the output of file and directory names. Or do you want to list all subdirectories of `/data/dataold`, then use `find /data/dataold -maxdepth ...` You should not yet accept the answer if it is unclear or doesn't work for you.

Comment: There are 1 million folders. It takes hours to calculate, I'll reply again tomorrow. But I think it has to be du -sh * to provide the answer I want.

Comment: It may be normal that both solutions will take some time for a large number of subdirectories. I expect the first solution (with `find`) to be slower.

Comment: Bodo, using du -sh * provides the answer I want. When I just use du -sh it doesn't give any output yet, it's trying to calculate the whole size. When I used du -sh * it already listed the small text and sh files and was struggling to find the size of the individual folders.

Comment: @jrdba123 I did not suggest to run `du -sh` without other arguments. Read the documentation of `find` and its `-exec` option. It will run the command multiple times and replace `{}` with a file or directory name. I added some explanation to the answer.

Comment: Bodo, unable to compile commands, crashes before compiling. Would it be better to do this by outputting to a text file with nohup? Or any idea how I can solve it in less time? It's an important topic and I'm really running out of time.

Comment: @jrdba123 There is nothing to compile. What command exactly do you use? What error message do you get?

Comment: Use `-exec du -sh {} +` (which executes `du -sh` once for every time the linux arg buffer is filled, approx 2MB) instead of `-exec du -sh {} \;` (which executes `du -sh` once for every file/directory).   The former is **much** faster.    BTW, to find directories >= 20GiB, use just `du -s` (without the `-h`) and pipe the output into an awk script or something, e.g. : `find data/dataold/exports -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec du -s {} + | awk '$1 >= 21474836480'`

Comment: Note that calling several independent invocations of `du` (like with `find -exec`) may give different numbers if there are hard links across those top level directories, as they won't  get deduplicated if found by different invocations of `du`.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to summarize and then let `du` do the work. Apply `sort` with `-h`uman order then cap at a specific size:

```
du -h /data/dataold/exports/ | sort -h
```

use `-r` in `sort` for listing in reverse order, i.e. large to small files.

For selecting the size, a simple trick with `awk` would do:

```
du -h /data/dataold/exports/ | awk -F'G' '$1~/^[0-9]+$/ && $1>=20' | sort -h
```

I.e.: use `G` (from the GB size output) as field separator, check if the field is a number only (to exclude wrong matches with the G-separator) and then select numbers larger 20 only. Sorting is optional here.